# how to fix the Net::SSH::Expect "SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out" issue while using Parallel::Forkmanager?

Tags: perl, ssh, parallel-processing

When I use the Parallel::Forkmanager to accomplish parallel process for remote ssh, I met "SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out" issue if the remote device is unreachable and then the STDOUT is totally messed up.
So how can I fix this messed STDOUT issue?
Why we can use the eval{ ssh operation } to work around?
Thanks.

Comment: Net::SSH::Expect is quite unreliable. As Chankey has already pointed out, use Net::OpenSSH, or even better, [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-OpenSSH-Parallel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH), it would even let you run the operations in parallel in all the hosts without too much hassle.

You can also try increasing the `timeout`.

Another possible solution might be something like below

```
my $retry_count = 0;
  while(1){
    $rc = eval{$ssh->login();};
    last if defined $rc;
    last if $retry_count >= $max_retry_count;
    $retry_count++;
    sleep 1;
  }
```

Also see: [Net::SSH::Perl, Net::SSH::Expect crashes script if host is unreachable](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=794847)