# What causes an "SSHAuthenticationError login timed out" error?

Tags: perl, authentication, ssh, cpan

My script uses [`Net:SSH::Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect). Occasionally I get the following error:

> SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out

Many people have posted the same question here at Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

One way to solve this is by adding a time-out. In spite of adding time-out, I still see this error — not always, but occasionally. Any suggestions?

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
               host     => 'ip',
               password => 'pwd',
               user     => 'username',
               raw_pty  => 1,
               timeout => 5
      );
```

Comment: Retry the authentication step until it does succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this to be the best/easiest solution: [how to fix the Net::SSH::Expect “SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out” issue while using Parallel::Forkmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073661/how-to-fix-the-netsshexpect-sshauthenticationerror-login-timed-out-issue-w/24074624#24074624).  Below is my version with a few tweaks to facilitate cut and paste.

```
my $retry_count = 0;
my $max_retry_count = 5; # or whatever
while(1)
{
    my $rc = eval{$ssh->login();};
    last if defined $rc;
    last if $retry_count >= $max_retry_count;
    $retry_count++;
    sleep 1;
}
```